# Mesh/Texture Deformation In Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a scene set up in Blender, it's a long concrete hallway with lights, but it looked bad and plain in EEVEE. So i switched to cycles but the mesh looked deformed. I have no idea why this happens, any way to fix?[image: Rendering Engine Set To Cycles]

https://pasteall.org/blend/d96dd4abecae4e10a7bccd4ac6956c96

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? Just keep the important part, upload and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here: https://pasteall.org/blend/d96dd4abecae4e10a7bccd4ac6956c96